# Integral of Summation (power series)

Tags: calculus, integration, summation, power-series

[image]

Could someone guide me through this process, I am confused on how you can take an integral of the factorial or whatever is going on in the problem.

In the context of this problem, the summation is obtained through the known mclaurin series for sin(x).

Comment: The only thing being integrated is the x term, everything else is constant so you can use the normal rules you know of

Comment: Oh, I see....................

Comment: Yeah if it helps you can move the integral sign all the way next to the term containing x so you can see that, since it's an indefinite integral a constant term is supplied at the end

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about
\begin{align}
\int\sin x^2\,dx&=\int\left(x^2-\frac{x^6}{3!}+\frac{x^{10}}{5!}-
\cdots+(-1)^n\frac{x^{4n+2}}{(2n+1)!}+\cdots\right)\,dx\\
&=\int x^2\,dx-\int\frac{x^6}{3!}\,dx+\int\frac{x^{10}}{5!}\,dx-
\cdots+\int(-1)^n\frac{x^{4n+2}}{(2n+1)!}\,dx+\cdots\\
&=C+\frac{x^3}3-\frac{x^7}{3!\times 7}+\frac{x^{11}}{5!\times 11}
-\cdots+(-1)^n\frac{x^{4n+3}}{(2n+1)!(4n+3)}+\cdots?
\end{align}

Comment: I hate when I'm on mobile and spot questions I can answer so I'm left to comment, nice illustration